# Автоматическое создание поддоменов в Apache (MAMP)

Tags: apache, macos, mac, mamp

Использую *MAMP* (*Mac OS*). В конце `httpd.conf` дописал следующее:

```
UseCanonicalName Off

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName loc
    ServerAlias *.loc
    VirtualDocumentRoot /Volumes/HDD/Sites/%1
</VirtualHost>
```

Но при попытке постучаться на *mysite.loc* (есть такая папка `mysite`) говорит, что веб-страница недоступна. Модуль `vhost_alias` включен. Что делаю не так?

**Обновление**

Разобрался. Нужно было прописать адрес в `/etc/hosts`. Однако я хотел добиться автоматического добавления поддоменов или даже доменов (без манипуляций с hosts). Реально ли добиться такого результата манипуляциями с *Apache*? Или тут нужно колдовать с *DNS*?

Answer (score 1):

> Нужно было прописать адрес в `/etc/hosts`

это нужно *http*-клиенту, чтобы знать, куда посылать запросы.

*http*-серверу это не требуется.

поэкспериментируйте (подставив вместо `127.0.0.1` *ip*-адрес машины, где работает ваш *http*-сервер):

```
$ curl -H 'host: blablabla.loc' http://127.0.0.1
```

---

забавные примеры:

```
$ curl -I -H 'host: google.com' http://yandex.ru
HTTP/1.1 406 Not acceptable

$ curl -I -H 'host: yandex.ru' http://google.com
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://www.google.com/
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Fri, 07 Aug 2015 19:08:58 GMT
Server: sffe
Content-Length: 219
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Comment: Мой http-сервер находиться на локальной машине(127.0.0.1). Существует папка Sites/ в которой лежат папки с сайтами (например Sites/mysite/) к которым я хочу обращаться (соответсвенно mysite.loc). Однако простого добавления папки недостаточно что бы обратиться к ней. Необходимо так же внести путь(mysite.loc) в hosts файл(а я хочу этого избежать). Насколько я понял, дабы не редактировать каждый раз hosts файл необходимо сконфигурировать DNS сервер таким образом, что бы он меня автоматом перенаправлял. Но как это сделать в Mac OS X не ясно. Вот и вопорос. Ткните в мануал.

Comment: это совсем другой вопрос. задавайте его, пожалуйста, нажав кнопку «[задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом верхнем углу любой страницы сайта.